# Scanner Safety Reading User Input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have not been able to find a good summary of the safety or lack of it when using Scanner *specifically* when asking for user input (as opposed to reading from a text file). I know in C, there are many dangers in reading user input, and we constantly need to be vigilant against things like Buffer Overflows.

I once spoke to someone who said they could easily break my program if I used the Scanner class. At that moment, I didn't press her too much on it, but it got me thinking: how much protection do I need to build in when reading user input (Strings, ints, etc.)?

Several examples of the kinds of attacks she meant: input being too long for the String to actually hold (over ~2 billion chars, and without \n), thus causing an exception. Inputting numerical values in if asking for a name. Perhaps even breaking the scanner and forcing it into undefined behavior in more complex ways?

I was thinking one way of protecting against this by having a try-catch around a Scanner.nextLine() to protect against input that's too long, or maybe even reading char by char and making sure it matches what I need (though I found out hasNext() doesn't really work for user input, only file reading).

What I'm really asking is: what is the best way to protect against someone purposefully trying to break your Scanner and cause an Exception or "undefined behavior"? Is a Scanner really the best tool for this? Are there other Classes you prefer when keeping malicious people in mind?

Comment: You can't control what a user is entering but why do you think there is a problem with the `Scanner` class? Please [edit] your question to include an example of an input which is a problem with the `Scanner` class.

Comment: Of course `Scanner` will throw exceptions if it encounters unexpected input - what else should it do when a call to `nextInt()` is made and user types in 'blah'. Your duty is to make sure you handle the errors that are expected to happen gracefully ("Invalid input: 'blah'") in your application or exit gracefully and notify the user when the error is unexpected. A program crashing is (usually) not a security issue. Every software crashes from time to time.

Comment: `Scanner` is as safe as the whole Java ecosystem is - it probably has some yet undisclosed security issues like any other piece of software in the universe. But it also has a huge amount of people behind it fixing the reported errors and doing security testing.

Comment: Handling user input on the other hand is a completely different beast. But I'm not sure if you asked about that.

Comment: Back to security - it's highly unlikely that your colleague has found an undisclosed security issue with `Scanner`. But if this is the case she should report it.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry about my English. I just want to be help :)

I think try-catch will solve all your problems.
all try like over 2 billion chars will be catch.
No- problem. wow.

But, there are other options.
U can use FileReader or FileInputStream.
Here is example.

```
try{//Use FileReader 
    File file = new File("text.txt");
    FileReader file_reader = new FileReader(file);
    int cur = 0;
    while((cur = file_reader.read()) != -1){
        System.out.print((char)cur);
    }
    file_reader.close();
}catch (Exception e) {e.getStackTrace();}
```

And

```
try {//Use FileInputStream
    String filePath = "text.txt";
    FileInputStream fileStream =  new FileInputStream( filePath );
    byte[ ] readBuffer = new byte[fileStream.available()];
    while (fileStream.read( readBuffer ) != -1){
        System.out.println(new String(readBuffer));
    }
    fileStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {e.getStackTrace();}
```

I don't know which way is great to defense.
But I know use FileInputStream is good. it's faster.

Bye. I hope you fell this answer not bad. :)

Comment: First example contains a typo. Second example doesn't work.

Comment: Hello user207421! Thanks for Comment.
I recheck second one, and it work! wow. 
i don't know why it doesn't work on your computer. sorry.
and, please teach me where typo is.
and sorry about terrible English :)

Comment: Sorry, the answer isn't helpful. I specifically said that I'm asking about *reading user input on console*, not reading from a file. I upvoted your answer to take off the -1 anyways.